# Where can I find the command line editor

Tags: command-line

I am trying to find the command line package as I am wanting to install replicator g onto my system as I am involved with a 3d printing package.  But for the life of me I cannot find it I'm a newby at LINUX so need a lot of help. I have tried to locate in all menus and packages and then even tried to download one.

Nigel

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu with Unity? Open the Dash (the button on the top left) and type software center (if you really want the terminal, type terminal).

Answer (score 0):

It's normally called 'terminal'

Answer (score 0):

Some ways to access the terminal:

- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>T</kbd>
- by typing `terminal` in the dash (open the dash by pressing the windows key)
- <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + (<kbd>F1</kbd> - <kbd>F6</kbd>) (Note: you will leave the desktop and enter the full command line environment, get back with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F7</kbd>)